# Syntax error with 'if or' in python. Not sure what's wrong with the code

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax, syntax-error

```
for i in range(0,len(qList)):
    response=(input((stringify(aList[i])))
    if (response==cList[i]) or ((" "+response) in aList[i]):
```

Where cList is a list of strings, and aList is a list of lists of strings.
stringify is a helper function that generates a string by combining the elements of a list.
One of the strings has a " " before it. The purpose of this is to allow the user to enter either a number (found in cList) or the exact text (found in a sublist of aList).

I'm really not sure where I'm going wrong to be honest, I've tried a few different things.

Comment: Try counting the parentheses in the second line.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on the preceding line:

```
response=(input((stringify(aList[i])))
#        1     23         4        432 ?
```

You are using *way to many* of those parentheses anyway, the following suffices:

```
response = input(stringify(aList[i]))
if response == cList[i] or " " + response in aList[i]:
```

If you are trying to access elements from `aList`, `bList` and `cList` in parallel, consider using `zip()`:

```
for a, b, c in zip(aList, bList, cList):
    response = input(stringify(a))
    if response == c or " " + response in a:
```

Comment: ...and if OP had just inserted `print(response)` it might have revealed this